# Can I define a Typescript map having a value constraint corresponding with each value's key?

Tags: typescript, generics, key, constraints, discriminated-union

In [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQCMBnGKHGfbGBCJOAbwCg44YBPMYALjlKmQBzANwtESUphS8kAVwC2hNKIC%20TJqEixxqDDjwBhKMEyoqNOnFCokAE2IESZCudr1mrDl14AibMdNgH1V1TWh4ZF0sXDgAMVkAG3QEBNdLa2A7ByJ%20F2o3RjEvHjgfdETkhOCmNQ1wcJ00aLwAZSQICAAvYDT6DKzHXOpews9OEp9idq6g0VZZFBSZBSUoELqteGKCfMsAXjgjEzNd%20gAfODaO7pGL%20KSU3tEmbDpSOH9jntPuI8CRg4eVhscbcPwBVA%20AA0YlYyEk0jgSGAAHc4AARQIACgAlAA6QTAGAAFQQ8mAuJhtVeEngU2u3wsSG4VxmANGwOKYPpM2hsPECJgMlRGOx%20MJJLJFJxMOBcAWNASwrRmNQuIJRNJ5NxcAA1HAAMwANgADGazTV1AB6K0wAAWCAcjo%20sigxhQCXYSIg8BpuWQwFsVnaskEdpeb3gCUwpF63CBrAA2vhxDsmYmfMUfABdbMAfm4IxqcEBtSY0djpwzn0COb2NZOTOEcHLMcoVcm026dZ5N1Ozxt9udKIgiSDCFsJgSnrYdqgEDRmA%20EHkYBSaCsbugcCkQboM6X90qIxHY7gSh32FwYFQQbtaGArcr6bKFRSPa7jLczaAA) I would like to create a map containing at most a single action of each type in the Action union. Each of the unioned types is differentiated by having a different string literal property 'type'. I have a definition for this map which compiles but is too loose...

```
const lastAction:{
    [A in Action["type"]]?:Action 
} = {}
```

The constraint on keys within the `lastAction` map enforces that...

- the key is a "type" property from some Action type
- the value must be some Action type

...it doesn't currently enforce that the key and the value are from the ***same*** Action type. Ideally the last line of the playground would fail as a compiler error as it attempts to assign an Action having type "snooze" into a property with the name "fulfil".

`lastAction["fulfil"]=snoozeAction`

I'm just missing the obvious here. I'm certain there's some way to do this with distributive conditionals or something even simpler. The pseudo-code below is junk Typescript as Generics don't work on a per property basis like this but it gives an idea of what I'm after...

```
const lastAction: {
    [key:A["type"]]:A extends Action
} = {};
```

Comment: It is ugly but perhaps works? const lastAction: { [A in Action["type"]]?: A extends 'create' ? CreateAction : A extends 'fulfil'? FulfilAction: A extends 'snooze'? SnoozeAction: never } = {}

Comment: Thanks ABOS. However, I think is fairly fundamental to the solution that the definition of the lastAction map should track the Action union, rather than duplicating its definition. Otherwise the duplicate could introduce inconsistencies and errors. If I was to redeclare keys and value types, it's also a bit easier to just make each literal key and its corresponding type explicit in the original map type. However this doesn't resolve the core issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Typescript 4.1's [key remapping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types), this is incredibly easy:

```js
const lastAction:{
    [A in Action as A["type"]]?: A 
} = {}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I hoped for, and answers this question, although it raises another question now at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369273/cannot-assign-correctly-typed-member-to-map It's more appropriate to treat that separately given I believe you answered this one.