# Cannot assign correctly typed member to map

Tags: typescript, undefined, assign, discriminated-union

Although I generally understand the reason for Typescript errors and can fix them, this one has me flummoxed.

In [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYSmE1QEFsYEIk4BvAKDjhgE8xgAuOAImyJODcA3I0RIAzjEwouSAK4BbAEZoRAX3r1QkWGNQYceAGJyANugSnylanVGt2XbujMXTw0cknSYsxSqh1TW1oeAc8ayoaAF4CfjIKKLgAHzgTc0tI6hEtcFDmNjwAFUxxAGs4WIYmHBsJDiykAG0AXXoNehckRNtIMDMBABlSmEbxAAopco4S8oBKaqY4bGpJOFMRxo5FpaWm0jE4RrhSo6bucO4WloB%20LgPRJjVKug1d9Gg4cZWJeFqkiDoZilMo3AB0-1WczsuyYPzWkKQRUKL0RYPCIlhy1W8A2kkaAElfj4XnjRj0kOCmojkexbmCvFIUJjYQggeMyYTiSg4AAyXnrTYUoneHkAPhOFIZ3Jg0J2sJ%20lHkwBZuzesM5FOpFNpwBaqIpqrg6qYRBgcigNE1dSC9CAA) I rely on the answer from [Can I define a Typescript map having a value constraint corresponding with each value's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365760/can-i-define-a-typescript-map-having-a-value-constraint-corresponding-with-each) to create a map with correctly typed properties but I found that I cannot assign a member.

I would expect Typescript to be able to reason that it was assignable. The error is quite weird. Given that the property is optional I'd expect it to accept undefined, but not complain when it's a concrete object which is guaranteed to match the constraint. Within the populateLastActions the assignment `lastAction[actionType] = action` causes an error.

```
const lastAction: {
    create?: CreateAction | undefined;
    fulfil?: FulfilAction | undefined;
}
Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'CreateAction' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

Comment: I think it's because create? can either be defined or undefined so if you simply make it as create instead of create? the error should go.

Comment: This has to do with what I've been calling [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and you're probably going to need to work around it either with [redundancy](https://tsplay.dev/nmqVJW) or a [type assertion](https://tsplay.dev/Qmb9dN).